# Как правильно? Вот думаю

Tags: орфография

> Наша дружба *годами да веками* **неразрушаема / не разрушаема**!

Comment: Вот читаю: годами да веками... Думаю, не кот ли насочинял, смотрю - и правда - кот!

Comment: Там другое летоисчисление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:  *Наша дружба годами да веками **неразрушаема**!*

**Пояснение**

1. ***Разрушать*** — переходный глагол, ***разрушаемый*** — причастие, так что можно предположить раздельное написание НЕ при наличии зависимого слова в Т.п.  **[Розенталь, пункт 13 и 14.](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)**

Но здесь "годами да веками" использовано в значении"вечно", поэтому НЕ пишется слитно.  Сравнить: ВЕКАМИ **нетронутая** земля (в значении прилагательного); рябина, **не тронутая** осенними заморозками (причастный оборот). **[Розенталь, пункт 5.](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80)**

2. **Пример**

   Наталья Лозинская "Рельефный хребет Карадага..."

   ```
   Под солнцем стоит и ветрами,
   неразрушаем годами,
   время явит под ногами
   тем, кто с любовью придёт.
   ```
3. В текстах чаще используется прилагательное ***неразрушимый***

[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)